# Unable to modify categories in magento due to error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, category, adminhtml

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php:153 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout() 
#1 /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout)) 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs') 
#3 /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()  
#4 /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): in /var/www/vhosts/Site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php on line 153


$this->addTab('products', array(
  'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category Products'),
  'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'adminhtml/catalog_category_tab_product',
    'category.product.grid'
  )->toHtml(),
));
```

Hello, i have had this error for sometime now but cannot seem to find the problem i have been over the file in question that is returning the error and looked through
   app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\etc\adminhtml.xml
   app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\etc\config.xml

and they are both correct and exactly the same as what is package with plain magento.

we haven't added any modules or changed any core code files this error has just appeared, if anyone could help this would be great.

This only seems to happen when trying to go to the category admin page.

header_nav -> catalog -> manage categories

Comment: As far as i can see this is due to an issue with a module installed id recommend disabling your modules 1 by 1 to see which is causing the error and then posting the config.xml file to here for that module

Comment: @DavaGordon I have already been through and disabled all the modules one by one to find the issue, even when i tested disabling every custom module (and clearing cache and re-indexing, all that stuff) the error was still present its definitely an issue with the magento core :/

Comment: if your magento core remains unchanged then reupload the core folder from a new package downloaded from magneto just make sure it is exactly the same version

Comment: @DavaGordon i have just been through and done this and it is still getting the same error, i have double checked that all caches were cleared and new files were fresh from a new zip downloaded from the magento site :/

Comment: Right well if that is the case it must either be a custom extension issue or a theme issue try enabling the default theme

Comment: As @DavaGordon mentioned, disable any extension you might have added, clear every cache as well as *restart the webserver/php-fpm* to clean php OPCache